# Is there a SoundCloud and MP3 player?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mp3, soundcloud, audio-player

I was wondering if there was a player that played MP3 links and SoundCloud URLs? If anyone knows of such a thing, or has any tips on making one, that'd be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An easy thing you could do for playing MP3 links in the browser would be to **copy and paste the following into your address bar** (replacing `{{mp3-url}}` with your URL):

```
data:text/html,<audio controls> <source src="{{mp3-URL}}" type="audio/mp3"> Your browser does not support the audio element. </audio>
```

This should work on any modern browser (Chrome, Firefox, etc.).